# How to calculate cex.axis automatically so to fit to the maximal width possible (in R)?

Tags: r, data-visualization

Let's say we created a plot, with labels:

```
plot(1, xlab = "text", ylab = "text times three") # text too small
```

In this plot there is still a lot of free region to enlarge the text.  We could do so by using cex.lab, like this:

```
par(cex.lab = 2)
plot(1, xlab = "text", ylab = "text times three")
```

Questions:

1. Is there a way to know what is the largest cex.lab possible, without the text getting over the borders?
2. Is it possible to do that separately for each component of the axis? (so to have a different fitting of cex.axis to the xlab vs the ylab) ?

Comment: In your Q2, do you mean `cex.lab` instead of `cex.axis`?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Surely when you include your graph within another document, the text sizes will now look too big.

Comment: This is really an R-code question, not a stats question.

Comment: John - you are right. But when I get to these, it is always borderline for me if to put them here or stackoverflow.  Thanks for the answer either way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following uses calls to par(), strheight() and strwidth() to fit within the borders of the plot area and the edges of the margin for the text.  They don't rescale together the same so this will give you a framework for redrawing your graph if you change the overall dimensions.  If you want something different this will be good to build on.  If you want to take up more of the margin area you need to look at parameters for the number of lines in a margin, lineheight, etc.  par() is what you need to do what you want but your question is vague.  This will do an interpretation of it.

```
sx <- 'my x-label'
sy <- 'my y-label'
plot(rnorm(4), ann = FALSE)
#work out string width max
maxcexXh <- par('pin')[1]/strwidth(sx,'inches')
maxcexYh <- par('pin')[2]/strwidth(sy,'inches')
#work out string height max
maxcexXv <- (par('mai')[1]/par('mar')[1])/strheight(sx,'inches')
maxcexYv <- (par('mai')[2]/par('mar')[2])/strheight(sy,'inches')
maxcexX <- min(maxcexXh, maxcexXv)
maxcexY <- min(maxcexYh, maxcexYv)
title(xlab = sx, cex.lab = maxcexX)
title(ylab = sy, cex.lab = maxcexY)
```

This likely is staying within the height of the string on your computer.  If you made the text much longer it would stay within the width.

My guess is that after you've done this you'll realize it's not a good idea.

Comment: That's not working for me (you probably need to edit out the `cex.lab = mycex` part of the call to `plot()` to get that example to run) as the y-axis label is half outside the plot window and the x-axis label extends across the axis and into the plot region.

Comment: Nice answer John.  Why do you think this is not a good idea ?

Comment: the sizes on each side could vary enough that that would be distracting.  I think a good idea could be made of it by simply combining the min() of each separate axis to the min of all of the variables.  But that isn't what you asked for.  It could then be wrapped into a nice function you use frequently called getMaxLabelCEX()

Comment: Thanks John, that makes sense - I'll wrap that later and possibly republish it (with credit).  Thanks again :)    Tal

Answer (score 5):

I can't think of an answer to Q1, but Q2 can be done via separate calls to `title()`. Here's an example

```
x <- 1:10
y <- runif(10)
plot(y ~ x, ann = FALSE)
title(ylab = "my Y axis label", cex.lab = 2)
title(xlab = "my X axis label", cex.lab = 3)
```

But I don't see the value in doing this, as won't the user be drawn to the fact that the labels are drawn to a different size? If they are (I would be) then the user will not be focussing on what the plot is designed to show.

Comment: It won't fit text labels to the maximum available space in the margins (which is what the OP ask for, to my understanding).

Comment: @chl; my opening line says I can't think of an answer to Q1, but Q2 *can* be done via my example, substituting in the maximum values for cex.lab in place of where I have `2` and `3` now. That was just an example of how to label the plot separately and never claimed to answer Q1. Maybe I misread/misinterpretted what Tal wanted with his Q2 though? Your reading of Q2's meaning seems obvious if Q1 is TRUE, hence I thought Tal was aksing the Q2 I answered...?